# Extract three values from regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a list which contains 1000 of records. All look like that:

(string, may contain more than one word) (integer number) x (float number) mm

For example:

```
Round 3 x 2.0 mm

Star 12 x 45.0 mm

Oval CAB 5 x 6.0 mm
```

I have to extract three values (string, integer, float) and put them into the table. I rarely work with regular expressions and can't find the way to get them without messing up (previous tries resulted with "Round3x", "3x20mm", wtf). Anyone knows how to do that?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: _..previous tries resulted with..._ If you show us the code, we maybe could help you finding out issues... but its up to you ;)

Comment: I don't want to ruin your minds :) also, I do not expect complete solution ofc, maybe some kind of suggestion or redirection to proper sources of knowledge

Comment: _I don't want to ruin your minds_ If this means that you dont want to post the code then ok, have fun , I'm out

Comment: Regex can only **find** the three required values, but putting them in a table is another task. So you should write a program, which: 1. Reads source records in a loop. 2. Matches each record using a regex.
3. Creates a row in a table. But what is the "host" programming language? You should mark this post with a proper language tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)\s(\d+)\sx\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RkeHhq/1)